# Suddenly can't boot Ubuntu - won't get past the loading screen, possibly interrupted upgrade

Tags: boot, updates

I have Ubuntu 17 and was working on it. I shut down my computer, and when I turned it back on Ubuntu wouldn't boot. The GRUB screen appeared but Ubuntu won't get past the loading screen. I waited for an hour. I think my computer was downloading an update during my last time on it. Right now I am on the Windows 10 side of the dual-boot.

I have tried going into the *Advanced Options for Ubuntu* and booting an older kernel, and in recovery mode I have used `fsck`, `clean`, and `dpkg`.

Comment: did you try the `nomodeset` option?

Comment: Prior to Ubuntu 17, the symptoms you have noted resulted from the Nvidia driver. So I don't know if the Nvidia drivers are still an issue. You may need to purge the Nvidia drivers from the command line.  Start with this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/591146/ubuntu-desktop-not-working-when-suspend-resume-or-connecting-an-external-monitor or https://askubuntu.com/questions/546609/terminal-command-for-purge-of-nvidia-and-install-new-package  Do a search on Ask Ubuntu for how to purge the Nvidia drivers through the the command line (terminal).

Comment: I have an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz processor. It is a 64-bit operating system. I also have Intel graphics chip. I have no Nvidia. @ravery how would I put in the nomodeset option?

Comment: in grub press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit command. find the part that says "quiet splash" add "nomodeset' to  the end.

Comment: It makes the boot screen look weird. The Ubuntu loading sign is much bigger along with the loading dots. It doesn't change the circumstance though. I still won't load.

Comment: Interesting discovery. In the loading screen for Ubuntu, if I press any of the top row buttons, ctrl+alt+T, or arrow keys the screen turns black. May be more keys but I didn't look. If I press the button again it turns back to the loading screen. I don't know if this is relevant, but I hope it will help.

Comment: Please help. bump?